# Balanced payment php : Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::createCard()

Tags: php, fatal-error, balanced-payments

I've installed the [balanced-php](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php) library, and I'm walking through the [tutorial to create a buyer](http://balancedpayments.com/docs/php/buyer).

I'm receiving the following error when I try to create a card:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::createCard();
```

I'm using version 0.3.

Comment: Add bit more details if you want a relevant answer from relevant people. We can not help without the background of error.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in version 0.3 of the balanced-php library.

The issue is that the bootstrap.php file within the Balanced library was not registering the classes correctly when the library is referenced and we've since released version 0.5 which fixes this issue.

Upgrading to version 0.5 of the library will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So you have outdated docs on https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php as provided on your site?

I am confused, are you saying the docs you provided us as per the instructions are incorrect and outdated?

Would you mind providing me with updated links to the proper docs as we have been following your instructions for a week as documented on your site...

Comment: Hey Weblance, I can assure you it's not outdated, I have added additional instructions to the README (https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php#quickstart) which show how to get it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I created a class for balancedpayment.com integration. It is for cakephp . But you can use it anywhere.

```
https://github.com/mohsinkabir/balancedpayments.com-integration-using-cakephp
```